# Does LDAP have an "integrated security" mode?

Tags: authentication, iis-7, ldap

I'm trying to change my LDAP connection to work over SSL. However, the SSL connection is authenticated meaning it would normally require a username and password where the standard connection does not:

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://myExampleLDAPServer.com:389/CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com" />
```

changed to

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP:///myExampleLDAPServer.com:636/CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com" />
```

but it wants a username and password, which I'd rather not store in the web.config at all. I have my connection to SQLServer set up with `integrated security=True` which uses the application pool's identity to authenticate against SQLServer. Is is possible to configure my LDAP connection to use integrated security as well?

Answer (score 1):

LDAP does not; However, you might be able to do this through extensions with [GSSAPI](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/GSSAPI) or [SPNEGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPNEGO)